# kernel compilation error

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, rhel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kernel can't find /dev/sda file during boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8405/kernel-cant-find-dev-sda-file-during-boot)

I got the following errors after new kernel compilation (linux-2.6.25.tar.bz2)

> mount: could not find filesystem '/dev/root'
>   setuproot: moving /dev failed: no such file or directory
>   setuproot: error mounting /proc: No such file or directory
>   setuproot: error mounting /sys: No such file or directory
>   switchroot: mount failed: No such file or directory
>   kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

How to troubleshoot?