# Kernel can't find /dev/sda file during boot

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, startup

I configured a gentoo kernel (kernel-2.6.36-gentoo-r5), but when I boot it can't mount `/dev/sda1`:

```
ALERT! /dev/sda1 does not exist . Dropping to a shell .
```

I use the shell to go to the `/dev` directory, and I find that it have no `sda*` or `hd*` files. However, when I boot into my Debian kernel (vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686), it can find and mount the `/dev/sda1` partition.

What's the problem? How can I fix it? I didn't add any module names to `/etc/modules.autoload.d/kernel-2.6` file to let them auto-load during boot -- is that the cause of the problem?

Comment: Could you please clarify - did you receive these errors when attempting to boot the new kernel or when attempting to compile the kernel? If the latter, was the compilation performed from within a running system or from an alternate environment such as a live cd?

Comment: @Tok: obvious enough he got that when booting the new kernel.

Comment: @pusp: Does your system normally uses initrd when booting the kernel?  If so, you probably need to rebuild that too.

Comment: What do you have set for root=UUID=?  I don't know if the UUID is being truncated or if it's set to /.

Comment: Did you build your kernel with SCSI and libata support or as a module?  Do you use an initrd?  Does that initrd load the modules?

Comment: What kind of device is /dev/sda? A SATA hard drive? SCSI? Also, what kind of file system is it using?

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention precisely how you rebuilt the kernel. This is a fairly complex process, and you should follow your distribution's recommendation. In fact, you should use your distribution's kernel unless you need some feature (such as a more recent set of drivers to support your hardware) that's not available precompiled.

There are two common pitfalls, either of which could cause the symptoms you observe.

- Maybe you forgot to compile a necessary driver. Kernel configuration is an arduous process, and it's easy to forget a crucial setting. In particular, make sure you have included the drivers necessary to reach your root filesystem: disk controller, partition scheme, filesystem, and if relevant volume management. Either these drivers must be built into the kernel (i.e. not modules), or you must have an initrd (in which case the initrd driver and the relevant filesystem must be built-in). Starting with your distribution's `.config` and changing only what you must is recommended.
- If you use an initrd, maybe you forgot to regenerate it, or to install it, or to tell your bootloader about it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have some driver required to access your root device. SATA, perhaps, or one of the SCSI modules used by that. Either you didn't build the driver, or you didn't put it in your initrd.

Comment: Q: Are we supposed to build the driver even when we don't touch the default configurations at all (assuming the kernel is the latest from kernel.org)?

Comment: @Anisha: yes. The default config does not enable all drivers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that you select the correct SATA drivers while configuring your kernel.  I don't know what your hardware is, so you'll need to find out for yourself which drivers will work for you.

I always build the SATA drivers into the kernel rather than as a module, it's just easier to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

For first-time Gentoo users, I strongly suggest using `genkernel` instead of plain `make menuconfig`. By default, `genkernel` will include all drivers it *thinks* is required.

If you have the time, re-run `genkernel` and *gradually* reduce the drivers you don't need, edit `grub.conf`, and reboot. Keep reducing. Note the settings (get the `.config` file).

In my case, I chose to do a re-installation, this time use the `.config` file and go straight to `make`. Not necessary, but I just dislike having many half-baked kernels lying around, plus some (possibly irrational) dislike of having to boot initrd.

(Well, at least that's how * I * did it. Takes time, but ultimately satisfying :-) )

Comment: yep, but reinstallation is not required.
Also, you might like `--menuconfig` switch.

Comment: yeah, I know it's not strictly required. But for some reasons I just dislike having to go through initrd when one can directly boot the kernel. Personal preference, I guess. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Running `make && make modules_install && make install` should not only build the kernel but install the kernel image (bzImage) and copy it to /boot/, create an initrd, and create a grub entry for both.

If this is not the command(s) and/or syntax that you were using I recommend attempting this process. If this is the process that you followed I recommend rebuilding your initrd with `mkinitrd` and verifying that the root device in the grub configuration accurately represents the system configuration.